# Statistical Test against randomness

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, bootstrap

I have the following problem:

vector = {1,0,0,1...}, only consists of 1 or 0, and size of vector is N.

I am calculating proportion of 1 in such vector.

Say, I got prop_1 = 0.96

Precisely, my null hypothesis is:

H0: 0.96 is random

HA: 0.96 is not random

And, I would like to reject H0 to show that 0.96 is not random.

What could be a procedure? Bootstrapping? Or some other ways?

Comment: What do you mean by "not random"? Is the vector supposed to have half 0 and half 1? Or something else? Also, "randomness" in a vector could mean a lot more than the proportion of all the values that are 1.

Comment: Why do you need to reject the obvious: "that 0.96 is not random"? How 0.96 (a fixed outcome) can be random? What's are your properly formulated hypotheses?

Comment: The rate at which 1 or 0 occur may not be 50:50. If it is 96% you would need a long series to reject randomness (0 or 1 occurring at random order). The test is Wald-Wolfowitz runs test, I guess.

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is if 0 and 1 are equally likely to appear, what is the likelihood that 0.96 is statistically different from the proportion of 0.50. In that case, you perform a binomial test of proportion. It can be a one-sided or two sided test.

Comment: The question as posed makes no sense. If I roll a fair 20-sided die that has one side marked '0' and 19 marked '1', I could easily get 96% ones, even with 1000 rolls, and the result would be 'random'. On the other hand, I could produce a set of 'coin flips' that are non-random (maybe I am Persi Diaconis and I can make them come up almost as I like) ... and so get 500 ones followed by 500 zeros. That would be a very non-random 50%.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but I think what's important here is to determine what your *expectation* of the ratio is, ahead of time before doing any test. That's what you base your test of whether the *outcome* is random or not. For example, suppose the string of 1s and 0s denote the outcome of tossing a coin with 1 if the coin lands on heads and 0 otherwise. If you expect a coin to be balanced, then the proportion of heads should be 0.5, and that's what you test against. If you expect your coin to be unbalanced, and the proportion of heads is say, 0.1, and that's what you test

Comment: I had to convert several attempts to answer your question into simple (although great) comments because it lacks clarification. Please, read them carefully in order to address the main issues that were raised.

Comment: Hello! My question possibly was not formulated correctly. I meant how to determine the statistical significance of 0.96 in such a vector. That is to say that 0.96 is not seen by chance in such vector. I thought of bootstrapping, say permute or randomly select 1 or 0 from original vector N times to produce bootstrap sample, calculate my estimate - proportion, do procedure 1000 times, and calculate mean of estimates. Then compare computed mean with 0.96, say via z-score and calculate p-value. I am not sure whether this procedure though is correct.